# DFExecutorUserError abfss://<data lake path>@<XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net>/ has invalid authority

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have created a data transformation which picks the 2 set of files from Azure Data Lake directory and then do the join and sink the resultant file in Azure Data Lake directory.
For the above scenario I created a Dataset which is pointing to the desired location where I have the 2 set of file which are .csv format. My dataset connection is failing and giving me below error

> Error code: DFExecutorUserError
> Details: abfss://<data lake path>@<XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net>/ has invalid authority.

When I change the directory location to something else, the dataset connection works fine. I did the research on this error, but not getting any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone finds this. In my case I was getting the

```
has invalid authority
```

because my path was missing an extra "/" forward slash

```
abfss:/blah@XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/some/path
```

instead of

```
abfss://blah@XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/some/path
```

because my use of `pathlib` mangled it

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("abfss://blah@XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net") / "some/other/path"
print(str(path))
abfss:/blah@XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/some/other/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Error suggests like a permissions issue with SAS authentication.

You can construct or modify SAS URI and assign `SignedPermission`

To construct the string-to-sign for an account SAS, use the following format:

```
StringToSign = accountname + "\n" +  
    signedpermissions + "\n" +  
    signedservice + "\n" +  
    signedresourcetype + "\n" +  
    signedstart + "\n" +  
    signedexpiry + "\n" +  
    signedIP + "\n" +  
    signedProtocol + "\n" +  
    signedversion + "\n"
```

Use this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas#constructing-the-account-sas-uri) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by only specifying the file path in the wildcard options